# wrong format of json string in an api call?

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

I try to bring the pdf file into a standard software, wrote the code, an exception is issued because of wrong format with json although json string corresponds exactly to the specified json of api call of standard software. can you please take a look if I wrote something wrong here or if I forgot something?
I covered some information with a star
Many Thanks

```
IRestResponse response3;

            client = new RestClient("http://***.***.***.*");
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("********", "*********");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            request = new RestRequest("/*****/api/******/*****/***", Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data");
            request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;

            request.AddParameter("Object", "{" +
                    "\"cabinet\":\"Posteingang\"," +
                    "\"name\":\"Posteingang\"," +
                    "\"objectTypeId\":\"2\"," +
                    "\"fields\":{" +
                    "\"Datum\":{\"value\":\"" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") + "\"}" +
                    "}" +
                "}");
            request.AddFile("file","C:/Users/*********/Documents/*********/Org.pdf","Org.pdf");

            MultipartFormDataContent multipartForm = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            byte[] file_bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("C:/Users/********/Documents/********/Org.pdf");

            multipartForm.Add(new ByteArrayContent(file_bytes, 0, file_bytes.Length), "profile_pic", "hello1.jpg");


            multipartForm.Add(new StringContent("Object"), "{" +
            "\"cabinet\":\"Posteingang\"," +
            "\"name\":\"Dokument\"," +
            "\"objectTypeId\":\"******\"," +
            "\"fields\":{" +
            "\"Datum\":{\"MAIL_SUBMIT_TIME\":{\"value\":\"" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") + "\"},\"Typ\":" +
            "{\"feld4\":{\"value\": \"Brief\"}},\"Absender\": {\"Mail_FROM\":{\"value\": \"*********\"}}}}}");

            response3 = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response3.Content);
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are combining JSON and file upload in a single request? Seems a bit weird to manually build a JSON object too. Maybe checkout JSON.net?

Comment: Why do you build the JSON string using string concatenation? This *guarantees* the result will be wrong and troubleshooting almost impossible. If you use a JSON serializer like JSON.NET or System.Text.Json you can just use eg` JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObject)` to serialize an object into a JSON string. The operation will be a LOT faster and use a lot less memory compared to the current code

Comment: I have three api calls, the first checked whether a current folder is available in the standard software which is specific, if the current folder with the current date is not available then the second api call adds a current folder and the third api call adds the current folder pdf file that is in a system folder. thx ok i will try serializing with it

Comment: Also seems a bit weird to add the JSON twice, once as form data as well and a second time as part of the multipart body.  (And, as an aside, doing `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")` twice could cause bugs if the first and second calls occur before and after midnight...)

Comment: true I am writing a function for the three calls and calling that function each time. true json should only appear once and should also serialize the entire json. Thanks for the answers